# League Scheduling program, inserting dates correctly

Tags: java

Having some problems with this program. I am new to Java and am trying to make a league scheduler. I have got to the point where the user can enter a number of teams needed, expected league start date and end date. Once the user selects the end date, a number of rounds are suggested to the user as this would be the number of weeks the league would need to go on for. Currently though, when the league generates, the dates print altogether, my question is how can I can the dates to print like  - "round 1 05/06/2018". Also, how can I change my program so an odd number can be accepted, similar to a 'bye'? 
I apologise for my ill knowledge of the subject, I have included a snippet of my code and a picture of my GUI so it gives more context.

Many thanks, 
Jack [image]

```
       void cyclicRoll(int cycle[], int teams) {

    int tmp = cycle[1];

    for(int i=1;i<teams-1;i++) {

        int pr = cycle[i+1];

        cycle[i+1] = tmp;

        tmp = pr;

    }

    cycle[1] = tmp;

}

void scheduleTournament(int teams, int round) {

    if (((teams%2 != 0) && (round != teams - 1))||(teams <= 0))

        throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    int[] cycle = new int[teams];

    int n = teams /2;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {                                

        cycle[i] = i + 1;

        cycle[teams - i - 1] = cycle[i] + n;


    }                        

    Date startDate = (jXDatePicker1.getDate());
    Date endDate = (jXDatePicker2.getDate());
    LocalDate dates = startDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
    LocalDate firstdate = startDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();

    DayOfWeek dayOfWeeek = dates.getDayOfWeek();

    LocalDate datee = endDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();  
    String listrep ="";
    String firstDateToPrint = firstdate.toString();

    while (!dates.equals(datee)) {
        jTextArea1.removeAll();
        if(dayOfWeeek == dayOfWeeek) {
            dates = dates.plusDays(7);

        }      
        String[] Itdates = {dates.toString()

            };

        for(String replacement : Itdates) {

            if ("".equals(listrep)) {
                listrep += replacement;
            } else {
                listrep +=  ", \n" + replacement ;
            }

        }
    }
    jTextArea1.append(firstDateToPrint + "\n");         
    jTextArea1.append(listrep);



    for(int d = 1; d <= round; d++) 
    {

        jTextArea1.append(String.format("Round %d\n",  d ));

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {

            jTextArea1.append(String.format("team %d - team %d\n",cycle[i],cycle[teams - i - 1]));

        }

        //Roll the cycle keeping the first constant
        cyclicRoll(cycle,teams);        
    }
}
String ref;
String teams;
String rounds;
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    jTextArea1.selectAll();
    jTextArea1.replaceSelection("");  
    teams = jTextField1.getText();
    int teamsToEnter = Integer.parseInt(teams);
    rounds = jTextField2.getText();
    int roundsToEnter = Integer.parseInt(rounds);
    ref = jTextField3.getText();
    jTextArea1.append("Ref "+ref + "\n");
    scheduleTournament(jTextField2,roundsToEnter);

}
```

Comment: `how can I change my program so an odd number can be accepted, similar to a 'bye'` - I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Assuming you mean an odd number of teams then you'd need to have an idea of how you'd arrange the rounds for that situation. That's not really Java specific but some general algorithmic problem you'd need to solve (how would _you_ as a league organizer do it on paper?).

Comment: Hi there, thank you for commenting. In this respect, it would be just adding an extra team if an odd number of teams is entered thereby making it even again.

Comment: As for the formatting, you'd just need to define it as needed. You might need to nest the loops, i.e. not `for(dates) {...} for(rounds) {...}` but rather `for(dates) { for(rounds at that date) { ... }}`. For further suggestions, could you provide examples of data and expected output?

Comment: So if you enter 7 for teams you'd get 8, right? Since the teams don't have names (yet), i.e. you don't need to handle that extra team separately, you could just do `teams += teams % 2` (modulo operator). `teams % 2` will be 0 for an even number and 1 for an odd number.

Comment: Some additional side notes: 1) I strongly suggest you use curly braces for _all_ blocks (e.g. `if (((teams%2 != 0) && (round != teams - 1))||(teams <= 0)) { throw new IllegalArgumentException(); }` - this will save you quite some trouble later on. 2) Check the Java code conventions: variable names should start with a lower case character and should be camelCase, i.e. `itDates` instead of `Itdates`. 3) Mind your variable names - they should convey some meaning. `d`, `datee` etc. don't tell much (at least me). Doing that will help reduce bugs due to misunderstandings.

Comment: I just need to try and sort the formatting problem as I tried nesting it and it ended up looping everything multiple times. By the way, that last comment worked and it now accepts the odd numbers, THANKS :D .

Comment: Thanks for all this help :D

Comment: As for the nesting: that's why I wrote `for(rounds at that date)`, i.e. you need a way to figure out which rounds belong to which date - it's probably just one round and multiple team constellations.